# Iterative method: Delete Linked List node using only one reference variable

Tags: java, linked-list, iteration

**SOLVED: CODE REFLECTS SOLUTION**

I have been working on a custom Linked List and need to delete a node with a given key only using **one reference to the list**.

I have managed to do this with two references (*Node previous, Node current*), but am a bit confused as how to approach this using only one.

My code works for cases except deleting the head node, and nodes that are not in the list ( I get nullpointer exception) when trying to delete '88' or a node that doesn't exist '100'.

```
Here is my test data from the list:
0) 88
1) 2
2) 1
3) 8
4) 11

// Iterative method to delete a node with a given integer key
// Only uses ONE reference variable to traverse the list.
private void delete (int key, Node x) {

    // Check if list is empty
    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Cannot delete; the list is empty.");
    }

    // Check if we're deleting the root node
    if (key == head.getKey()) {

        // Now the first in the list is where head was pointing
        removeFromHead();
    }

    // General case: while the next node exists, check its key
    for (x = head; x.getNext() != null; x = x.getNext()) {

        // If the next key is what we are looking for, we need to remove it
        if (key == x.getNext().getKey()) {

            // x skips over the node to be deleted.
            x.putNext(x.getNext().getNext());
        }
    } // End for
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Value delete (int key) {

    //check if list is empty
    if (head == null)
        //the key does not exist. return null to let the method caller know
        return null; 

    //check if we're deleting the root node
    if (key == head.getKey()) {
        //set the value of what we're deleting
        Value val = head.getNode().getValue();
        //now the first in the list is where head was pointing
        head = head.getNext();
        //there is now one less item in your list. update the size
        total--;
        //return what we're deleting
        return val;
    }

    // general case: while the next node exists, check its key
    for (Node x = head; x.getNext() != null; x = x.getNext()) {

        //check if the next node's key matches
        if (key == x.getNext().getKey()) {

            //set value of what we're deleting
            Value val = x.getNext().getNode().getValue();

            //x now points to where the node we are deleting points
            x.setNext(x.getNext().getNext());

            //there is now one less item in the list. update the size
            total--;

            //return what we're deleting
            return val; 
        }
    }


    //if we didn't find the key above, it doesn't exist. return null to let the
    // method caller know.
    return null; 
}
```

This is for `LinkedList<Value>`. General idea is there, but you'll have to tailor this to how you've set everything up.

Comment: Thanks! This made me realize what I was doing wrong! I really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have problems with the head and the tail of the list because you are not checking them properly.
You should compare the key the the head before entering the while loop. The first value that the loop checks is of the second node (`temp.getNext().getKey()`), so you never actually test the head.
Moreover, after the loop has ended and you check to see if the key is in the last node, you are also calling `getNext()`. If it was indeed the last node, then the next node is null and it has no `getKey()` method.

Comment: I have updated the code to attempt these changes. I am now only getting a nullpointer exception when I attempt to search for a non-existing key.

I added a boolean 'removed' to keep track of whether an element was removed or not.

Comment: @EvanBechtol I don't see the need for the extra boolean as you can simply return when finding an element and removing it. You still didn't fix the problem with last/not existing keys - at the worst case (key not in list) the while loop stops when `temp.getNext()==null` but right after that you use `temp.getNext.getKey(), which is why you're getting an exception.